# Null value when accessing variable in other classes (Combined Navigation & Tab Controller)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a navigation controller residing inside a tab bar controller and whenever I try to access a class from a class within the navigation controller all my values return (null).

This is how I'm trying to do it.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
NSString *searchQueryA;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchQueryA;
```

ThirdViewController.h

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@class MasterViewController;

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController {
code
}

@property (strong, retain) MasterViewController *masterViewController;
```

ThirdViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)showDetail:(id)sender {
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
appDelegate.searchQueryA = _searchField.text;
masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:masterViewController animated:YES];
}
```

MasterViewController.h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
{
NSString *searchQueryM;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *searchQueryM;
```

MasterViewController.m

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
 searchQueryM = appDelegate.searchQueryA;

 NSLog(@"%@", searchQueryM);
```

And in the log I can see that searchQueryM is (null). If I try to access the variable in AppDelegate from another class, that isn't involved with navigation controller, then it shows perfectly fine. What am I missing?

If you need to see more code I'd be happy to provide it.

EDIT:

For legibility I'll post code changes here:

I have the  delegate in my AppDelegate.h

As Leonardo pointed out I only alloc'd and init'd my AppDelegate. I changed that snippet to this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
searchQueryM = appDelegate.searchQueryA;
```

but still no go as searchQueryM still is (null).

This is what I do with searchQueryM

MasterViewController.h

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
{
NSString *searchQueryM;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *searchQueryM;
```

MasterViewController.m

```
@synthesize searchQueryM;
```

I'm fairly new to Objective-C (as well as OO-programming) and should probably read a book on it, but it seems to me like there isn't a lot more to it than that. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

**EDIT 2**

ThirdViewController.h

```
@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController {
UITextField *_searchField;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *searchField;
```

ThirdViewController.m

```
 @synthesize searchField = _searchField;

 ...

 - (IBAction)showDetail:(id)sender {
 _code_
 NSLog(@"%@", searchField.text);
 _code_
```

If i type in "asd" in the searchField textfield and output it with the log I get "asd".
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you alloc init your AppDelegate ?
The AppDelegate should be accessed with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

We should see how you normally initialize searchQueryM, you are getting null, probably because the AppDelegate get only allocated and init, but the logic that initialize its properties never gets called.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me , seems like I messed up with that one, still doesn't solve my problem though.

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

 searchQuery = appDelegate.searchQuery;

Change it to the code above, still get a null value. I have the <UIApplicationDelegate> in my AppDelegate.h

Comment: uhm, is _searchField an IBOutlet ? If so, did you connect trough InterfaceBuilder in ThirdViewController ? Put a breakpoint, or a Log statement in showDetail method and see if you are getting a proper value since then.

Comment: _searchField is an IBOutlet, it is connected and when logged I get the proper value. I'll post the code for _searchField up in the original post.

Comment: Just a note, of course you never alloc your app delegate, but you are using the sharedApplication delegate even in ThirdViewController ? Rememeber to change this in all your viewcontrollers and relevant classes.

Comment: That's it! I forgot to include it in ThirdViewController. I only alloc'd and init'd it. Strange though, as when I checked the value of the variable in AppDelegate it was what I had just changed it to. Many thanks Leonardo!